# Fancyhdr, problem with chapter titles

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I've asked my first question on the forum yesterday and I've done several mistakes in it, making the subject not understandable so I've decided to delete the question and start again properly....

I'm trying to set up the headers for my master thesis having page numbers and chapter titles for the even pages and section titles for the odd in it, with two different styles for the frontmatter and the mainmatter. I'm close to obtain what I want but I remain with several issues related to the titles in the frontmatter.

I'm trying to get rid of the "CHAPTER 0" wich remain before every title in the header as I just want to keep the title it self. I'm also trying to have the name of the chapter in capital letters but the name of the sections in small letters as it is (and works very well) in the mainmatter.

I shall say that for each section I've used `\pagestyle{frontmatter}` and `\pagestyle{mainmatter}`.

I cannot see the mistake I've done in the following preambule:

```
       \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}




\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, headheight = 20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

% Mise en page du livre
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

    \fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}
      \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{##1}}
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
      \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
      \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
      \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
      \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
    }

    \fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
      \fancyhf{}
      \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ ##1}}{}} 
      \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{} \ ##1}}
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
      \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
      \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
      \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
      \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
    }





%************************************************
%                                               *
%           COMMANDES PERSONNALISÉES            *
%                                               *
%************************************************

% Insérer des guillemets français
\newcommand{\g}[1]{\og#1\fg}




\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \pagestyle{frontmatter}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}




  \chapter{Introduction}

\section{Première section}

Nihil morati post haec militares avidi saepe turbarum adorti sunt Montium primum, qui divertebat in proximo, levi corpore senem atque morbosum, et hirsutis resticulis cruribus eius innexis divaricaturn sine spiramento ullo ad usque praetorium traxere praefecti.

Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.

Et quoniam inedia gravi adflictabantur, locum petivere Paleas nomine, vergentem in mare, valido muro firmatum, ubi conduntur nunc usque commeatus distribui militibus omne latus Isauriae defendentibus adsueti. circumstetere igitur hoc munimentum per triduum et trinoctium et cum neque adclivitas ipsa sine discrimine adiri letali, nec cuniculis quicquam geri posset, nec procederet ullum obsidionale commentum, maesti excedunt postrema vi subigente maiora viribus adgressuri.

Exsistit autem hoc loco quaedam quaestio subdifficilis, num quando amici novi, digni amicitia, veteribus sint anteponendi, ut equis vetulis teneros anteponere solemus. Indigna homine dubitatio! Non enim debent esse amicitiarum sicut aliarum rerum satietates; veterrima quaeque, ut ea vina, quae vetustatem ferunt, esse debet suavissima; verumque illud est, quod dicitur, multos modios salis simul edendos esse, ut amicitiae munus expletum sit.

Inter quos Paulus eminebat notarius ortus in Hispania, glabro quidam sub vultu latens, odorandi vias periculorum occultas perquam sagax. is in Brittanniam missus ut militares quosdam perduceret ausos conspirasse Magnentio, cum reniti non possent, iussa licentius supergressus fluminis modo fortunis conplurium sese repentinus infudit et ferebatur per strages multiplices ac ruinas, vinculis membra ingenuorum adfligens et quosdam obterens manicis, crimina scilicet multa consarcinando a veritate longe discreta. unde admissum est facinus impium, quod Constanti tempus nota inusserat sempiterna.

Quare talis improborum consensio non modo excusatione amicitiae tegenda non est sed potius supplicio omni vindicanda est, ut ne quis concessum putet amicum vel bellum patriae inferentem sequi; quod quidem, ut res ire coepit, haud scio an aliquando futurum sit. Mihi autem non minori curae est, qualis res publica post mortem meam futura, quam qualis hodie sit.

Mensarum enim voragines et varias voluptatum inlecebras, ne longius progrediar, praetermitto illuc transiturus quod quidam per ampla spatia urbis subversasque silices sine periculi metu properantes equos velut publicos signatis quod dicitur calceis agitant, familiarium agmina tamquam praedatorios globos post terga trahentes ne Sannione quidem, ut ait comicus, domi relicto. quos imitatae matronae complures opertis capitibus et basternis per latera civitatis cuncta discurrunt.

Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.

Circa hos dies Lollianus primae lanuginis adulescens, Lampadi filius ex praefecto, exploratius causam Maximino spectante, convictus codicem noxiarum artium nondum per aetatem firmato consilio descripsisse, exulque mittendus, ut sperabatur, patris inpulsu provocavit ad principem, et iussus ad eius comitatum duci, de fumo, ut aiunt, in flammam traditus Phalangio Baeticae consulari cecidit funesti carnificis manu.

Eminuit autem inter humilia supergressa iam impotentia fines mediocrium delictorum nefanda Clematii cuiusdam Alexandrini nobilis mors repentina; cuius socrus cum misceri sibi generum, flagrans eius amore, non impetraret, ut ferebatur, per palatii pseudothyrum introducta, oblato pretioso reginae monili id adsecuta est, ut ad Honoratum tum comitem orientis formula missa letali omnino scelere nullo contactus idem Clematius nec hiscere nec loqui permissus occideretur.

Horum adventum praedocti speculationibus fidis rectores militum tessera data sollemni armatos omnes celeri eduxere procursu et agiliter praeterito Calycadni fluminis ponte, cuius undarum magnitudo murorum adluit turres, in speciem locavere pugnandi. neque tamen exiluit quisquam nec permissus est congredi. formidabatur enim flagrans vesania manus et superior numero et ruitura sine respectu salutis in ferrum.

Eo adducta re per Isauriam, rege Persarum bellis finitimis inligato repellenteque a conlimitiis suis ferocissimas gentes, quae mente quadam versabili hostiliter eum saepe incessunt et in nos arma moventem aliquotiens iuvant, Nohodares quidam nomine e numero optimatum, incursare Mesopotamiam quotiens copia dederit ordinatus, explorabat nostra sollicite, si repperisset usquam locum vi subita perrupturus.

Post quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huius modi scrutabatur. quae singula narrare non refert, me professione modum, quod evitandum est, excedamus.

Ut enim quisque sibi plurimum confidit et ut quisque maxime virtute et sapientia sic munitus est, ut nullo egeat suaque omnia in se ipso posita iudicet, ita in amicitiis expetendis colendisque maxime excellit. Quid enim? Africanus indigens mei? Minime hercule! ac ne ego quidem illius; sed ego admiratione quadam virtutis eius, ille vicissim opinione fortasse non nulla, quam de meis moribus habebat, me dilexit; auxit benevolentiam consuetudo. Sed quamquam utilitates multae et magnae consecutae sunt, non sunt tamen ab earum spe causae diligendi profectae.

Excogitatum est super his, ut homines quidam ignoti, vilitate ipsa parum cavendi ad colligendos rumores per Antiochiae latera cuncta destinarentur relaturi quae audirent. hi peragranter et dissimulanter honoratorum circulis adsistendo pervadendoque divites domus egentium habitu quicquid noscere poterant vel audire latenter intromissi per posticas in regiam nuntiabant, id observantes conspiratione concordi, ut fingerent quaedam et cognita duplicarent in peius, laudes vero supprimerent Caesaris, quas invitis conpluribus formido malorum inpendentium exprimebat.


Unde Rufinus ea tempestate praefectus praetorio ad discrimen trusus est ultimum. ire enim ipse compellebatur ad militem, quem exagitabat inopia simul et feritas, et alioqui coalito more in ordinarias dignitates asperum semper et saevum, ut satisfaceret atque monstraret, quam ob causam annonae convectio sit impedita.

Haec ubi latius fama vulgasset missaeque relationes adsiduae Gallum Caesarem permovissent, quoniam magister equitum longius ea tempestate distinebatur, iussus comes orientis Nebridius contractis undique militaribus copiis ad eximendam periculo civitatem amplam et oportunam studio properabat ingenti, quo cognito abscessere latrones nulla re amplius memorabili gesta, dispersique ut solent avia montium petiere celsorum.

Et quia Mesopotamiae tractus omnes crebro inquietari sueti praetenturis et stationibus servabantur agrariis, laevorsum flexo itinere Osdroenae subsederat extimas partes, novum parumque aliquando temptatum commentum adgressus. quod si impetrasset, fulminis modo cuncta vastarat. erat autem quod cogitabat huius modi.

Post haec indumentum regale quaerebatur et ministris fucandae purpurae tortis confessisque pectoralem tuniculam sine manicis textam, Maras nomine quidam inductus est ut appellant Christiani diaconus, cuius prolatae litterae scriptae Graeco sermone ad Tyrii textrini praepositum celerari speciem perurgebant quam autem non indicabant denique etiam idem ad usque discrimen vitae vexatus nihil fateri conpulsus est.

Eodem tempore etiam Hymetii praeclarae indolis viri negotium est actitatum, cuius hunc novimus esse textum. cum Africam pro consule regeret Carthaginiensibus victus inopia iam lassatis, ex horreis Romano populo destinatis frumentum dedit, pauloque postea cum provenisset segetum copia, integre sine ulla restituit mora.

Nihil morati post haec militares avidi saepe turbarum adorti sunt Montium primum, qui divertebat in proximo, levi corpore senem atque morbosum, et hirsutis resticulis cruribus eius innexis divaricaturn sine spiramento ullo ad usque praetorium traxere praefecti.

Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.

Et quoniam inedia gravi adflictabantur, locum petivere Paleas nomine, vergentem in mare, valido muro firmatum, ubi conduntur nunc usque commeatus distribui militibus omne latus Isauriae defendentibus adsueti. circumstetere igitur hoc munimentum per triduum et trinoctium et cum neque adclivitas ipsa sine discrimine adiri letali, nec cuniculis quicquam geri posset, nec procederet ullum obsidionale commentum, maesti excedunt postrema vi subigente maiora viribus adgressuri.

Exsistit autem hoc loco quaedam quaestio subdifficilis, num quando amici novi, digni amicitia, veteribus sint anteponendi, ut equis vetulis teneros anteponere solemus. Indigna homine dubitatio! Non enim debent esse amicitiarum sicut aliarum rerum satietates; veterrima quaeque, ut ea vina, quae vetustatem ferunt, esse debet suavissima; verumque illud est, quod dicitur, multos modios salis simul edendos esse, ut amicitiae munus expletum sit.

Inter quos Paulus eminebat notarius ortus in Hispania, glabro quidam sub vultu latens, odorandi vias periculorum occultas perquam sagax. is in Brittanniam missus ut militares quosdam perduceret ausos conspirasse Magnentio, cum reniti non possent, iussa licentius supergressus fluminis modo fortunis conplurium sese repentinus infudit et ferebatur per strages multiplices ac ruinas, vinculis membra ingenuorum adfligens et quosdam obterens manicis, crimina scilicet multa consarcinando a veritate longe discreta. unde admissum est facinus impium, quod Constanti tempus nota inusserat sempiterna.

Quare talis improborum consensio non modo excusatione amicitiae tegenda non est sed potius supplicio omni vindicanda est, ut ne quis concessum putet amicum vel bellum patriae inferentem sequi; quod quidem, ut res ire coepit, haud scio an aliquando futurum sit. Mihi autem non minori curae est, qualis res publica post mortem meam futura, quam qualis hodie sit.

Mensarum enim voragines et varias voluptatum inlecebras, ne longius progrediar, praetermitto illuc transiturus quod quidam per ampla spatia urbis subversasque silices sine periculi metu properantes equos velut publicos signatis quod dicitur calceis agitant, familiarium agmina tamquam praedatorios globos post terga trahentes ne Sannione quidem, ut ait comicus, domi relicto. quos imitatae matronae complures opertis capitibus et basternis per latera civitatis cuncta discurrunt.

Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.

Circa hos dies Lollianus primae lanuginis adulescens, Lampadi filius ex praefecto, exploratius causam Maximino spectante, convictus codicem noxiarum artium nondum per aetatem firmato consilio descripsisse, exulque mittendus, ut sperabatur, patris inpulsu provocavit ad principem, et iussus ad eius comitatum duci, de fumo, ut aiunt, in flammam traditus Phalangio Baeticae consulari cecidit funesti carnificis manu.

Eminuit autem inter humilia supergressa iam impotentia fines mediocrium delictorum nefanda Clematii cuiusdam Alexandrini nobilis mors repentina; cuius socrus cum misceri sibi generum, flagrans eius amore, non impetraret, ut ferebatur, per palatii pseudothyrum introducta, oblato pretioso reginae monili id adsecuta est, ut ad Honoratum tum comitem orientis formula missa letali omnino scelere nullo contactus idem Clematius nec hiscere nec loqui permissus occideretur.

Horum adventum praedocti speculationibus fidis rectores militum tessera data sollemni armatos omnes celeri eduxere procursu et agiliter praeterito Calycadni fluminis ponte, cuius undarum magnitudo murorum adluit turres, in speciem locavere pugnandi. neque tamen exiluit quisquam nec permissus est congredi. formidabatur enim flagrans vesania manus et superior numero et ruitura sine respectu salutis in ferrum.

Eo adducta re per Isauriam, rege Persarum bellis finitimis inligato repellenteque a conlimitiis suis ferocissimas gentes, quae mente quadam versabili hostiliter eum saepe incessunt et in nos arma moventem aliquotiens iuvant, Nohodares quidam nomine e numero optimatum, incursare Mesopotamiam quotiens copia dederit ordinatus, explorabat nostra sollicite, si repperisset usquam locum vi subita perrupturus.

Post quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huius modi scrutabatur. quae singula narrare non refert, me professione modum, quod evitandum est, excedamus.

Ut enim quisque sibi plurimum confidit et ut quisque maxime virtute et sapientia sic munitus est, ut nullo egeat suaque omnia in se ipso posita iudicet, ita in amicitiis expetendis colendisque maxime excellit. Quid enim? Africanus indigens mei? Minime hercule! ac ne ego quidem illius; sed ego admiratione quadam virtutis eius, ille vicissim opinione fortasse non nulla, quam de meis moribus habebat, me dilexit; auxit benevolentiam consuetudo. Sed quamquam utilitates multae et magnae consecutae sunt, non sunt tamen ab earum spe causae diligendi profectae.

Excogitatum est super his, ut homines quidam ignoti, vilitate ipsa parum cavendi ad colligendos rumores per Antiochiae latera cuncta destinarentur relaturi quae audirent. hi peragranter et dissimulanter honoratorum circulis adsistendo pervadendoque divites domus egentium habitu quicquid noscere poterant vel audire latenter intromissi per posticas in regiam nuntiabant, id observantes conspiratione concordi, ut fingerent quaedam et cognita duplicarent in peius, laudes vero supprimerent Caesaris, quas invitis conpluribus formido malorum inpendentium exprimebat.


\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatter}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\chapter{C'est le chapitre 1}
\section{La section 1}





Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.

Circa hos dies Lollianus primae lanuginis adulescens, Lampadi filius ex praefecto, exploratius causam Maximino spectante, convictus codicem noxiarum artium nondum per aetatem firmato consilio descripsisse, exulque mittendus, ut sperabatur, patris inpulsu provocavit ad principem, et iussus ad eius comitatum duci, de fumo, ut aiunt, in flammam traditus Phalangio Baeticae consulari cecidit funesti carnificis manu.

Eminuit autem inter humilia supergressa iam impotentia fines mediocrium delictorum nefanda Clematii cuiusdam Alexandrini nobilis mors repentina; cuius socrus cum misceri sibi generum, flagrans eius amore, non impetraret, ut ferebatur, per palatii pseudothyrum introducta, oblato pretioso reginae monili id adsecuta est, ut ad Honoratum tum comitem orientis formula missa letali omnino scelere nullo contactus idem Clematius nec hiscere nec loqui permissus occideretur.

Horum adventum praedocti speculationibus fidis rectores militum tessera data sollemni armatos omnes celeri eduxere procursu et agiliter praeterito Calycadni fluminis ponte, cuius undarum magnitudo murorum adluit turres, in speciem locavere pugnandi. neque tamen exiluit quisquam nec permissus est congredi. formidabatur enim flagrans vesania manus et superior numero et ruitura sine respectu salutis in ferrum.

Eo adducta re per Isauriam, rege Persarum bellis finitimis inligato repellenteque a conlimitiis suis ferocissimas gentes, quae mente quadam versabili hostiliter eum saepe incessunt et in nos arma moventem aliquotiens iuvant, Nohodares quidam nomine e numero optimatum, incursare Mesopotamiam quotiens copia dederit ordinatus, explorabat nostra sollicite, si repperisset usquam locum vi subita perrupturus.

Post quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huius modi scrutabatur. quae singula narrare non refert, me professione modum, quod evitandum est, excedamus.

Ut enim quisque sibi plurimum confidit et ut quisque maxime virtute et sapientia sic munitus est, ut nullo egeat suaque omnia in se ipso posita iudicet, ita in amicitiis expetendis colendisque maxime excellit. Quid enim? Africanus indigens mei? Minime hercule! ac ne ego quidem illius; sed ego admiratione quadam virtutis eius, ille vicissim opinione fortasse non nulla, quam de meis moribus habebat, me dilexit; auxit benevolentiam consuetudo. Sed quamquam utilitates multae et magnae consecutae sunt, non sunt tamen ab earum spe causae diligendi profectae.

Excogitatum est super his, ut homines quidam ignoti, vilitate ipsa parum cavendi ad colligendos rumores per Antiochiae latera cuncta destinarentur relaturi quae audirent. hi peragranter et dissimulanter honoratorum circulis adsistendo pervadendoque divites domus egentium habitu quicquid noscere poterant vel audire latenter intromissi per posticas in regiam nuntiabant, id observantes conspiratione concordi, ut fingerent quaedam et cognita duplicarent in peius, laudes vero supprimerent Caesaris, quas invitis conpluribus formido malorum inpendentium exprimebat.


Unde Rufinus ea tempestate praefectus praetorio ad discrimen trusus est ultimum. ire enim ipse compellebatur ad militem, quem exagitabat inopia simul et feritas, et alioqui coalito more in ordinarias dignitates asperum semper et saevum, ut satisfaceret atque monstraret, quam ob causam annonae convectio sit impedita.

Haec ubi latius fama vulgasset missaeque relationes adsiduae Gallum Caesarem permovissent, quoniam magister equitum longius ea tempestate distinebatur, iussus comes orientis Nebridius contractis undique militaribus copiis ad eximendam periculo civitatem amplam et oportunam studio properabat ingenti, quo cognito abscessere latrones nulla re amplius memorabili gesta, dispersique ut solent avia montium petiere celsorum.

Et quia Mesopotamiae tractus omnes crebro inquietari sueti praetenturis et stationibus servabantur agrariis, laevorsum flexo itinere Osdroenae subsederat extimas partes, novum parumque aliquando temptatum commentum adgressus. quod si impetrasset, fulminis modo cuncta vastarat. erat autem quod cogitabat huius modi.

Post haec indumentum regale quaerebatur et ministris fucandae purpurae tortis confessisque pectoralem tuniculam sine manicis textam, Maras nomine quidam inductus est ut appellant Christiani diaconus, cuius prolatae litterae scriptae Graeco sermone ad Tyrii textrini praepositum celerari speciem perurgebant quam autem non indicabant denique etiam idem ad usque discrimen vitae vexatus nihil fateri conpulsus est.

Eodem tempore etiam Hymetii praeclarae indolis viri negotium est actitatum, cuius hunc novimus esse textum. cum Africam pro consule regeret Carthaginiensibus victus inopia iam lassatis, ex horreis Romano populo destinatis frumentum dedit, pauloque postea cum provenisset segetum copia, integre sine ulla restituit mora.

Nihil morati post haec militares avidi saepe turbarum adorti sunt Montium primum, qui divertebat in proximo, levi corpore senem atque morbosum, et hirsutis resticulis cruribus eius innexis divaricaturn sine spiramento ullo ad usque praetorium traxere praefecti.

Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.

Et quoniam inedia gravi adflictabantur, locum petivere Paleas nomine, vergentem in mare, valido muro firmatum, ubi conduntur nunc usque commeatus distribui militibus omne latus Isauriae defendentibus adsueti. circumstetere igitur hoc munimentum per triduum et trinoctium et cum neque adclivitas ipsa sine discrimine adiri letali, nec cuniculis quicquam geri posset, nec procederet ullum obsidionale commentum, maesti excedunt postrema vi subigente maiora viribus adgressuri.

Exsistit autem hoc loco quaedam quaestio subdifficilis, num quando amici novi, digni amicitia, veteribus sint anteponendi, ut equis vetulis teneros anteponere solemus. Indigna homine dubitatio! Non enim debent esse amicitiarum sicut aliarum rerum satietates; veterrima quaeque, ut ea vina, quae vetustatem ferunt, esse debet suavissima; verumque illud est, quod dicitur, multos modios salis simul edendos esse, ut amicitiae munus expletum sit.

Inter quos Paulus eminebat notarius ortus in Hispania, glabro quidam sub vultu latens, odorandi vias periculorum occultas perquam sagax. is in Brittanniam missus ut militares quosdam perduceret ausos conspirasse Magnentio, cum reniti non possent, iussa licentius supergressus fluminis modo fortunis conplurium sese repentinus infudit et ferebatur per strages multiplices ac ruinas, vinculis membra ingenuorum adfligens et quosdam obterens manicis, crimina scilicet multa consarcinando a veritate longe discreta. unde admissum est facinus impium, quod Constanti tempus nota inusserat sempiterna.

Quare talis improborum consensio non modo excusatione amicitiae tegenda non est sed potius supplicio omni vindicanda est, ut ne quis concessum putet amicum vel bellum patriae inferentem sequi; quod quidem, ut res ire coepit, haud scio an aliquando futurum sit. Mihi autem non minori curae est, qualis res publica post mortem meam futura, quam qualis hodie sit.

Mensarum enim voragines et varias voluptatum inlecebras, ne longius progrediar, praetermitto illuc transiturus quod quidam per ampla spatia urbis subversasque silices sine periculi metu properantes equos velut publicos signatis quod dicitur calceis agitant, familiarium agmina tamquam praedatorios globos post terga trahentes ne Sannione quidem, ut ait comicus, domi relicto. quos imitatae matronae complures opertis capitibus et basternis per latera civitatis cuncta discurrunt.

Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.

Circa hos dies Lollianus primae lanuginis adulescens, Lampadi filius ex praefecto, exploratius causam Maximino spectante, convictus codicem noxiarum artium nondum per aetatem firmato consilio descripsisse, exulque mittendus, ut sperabatur, patris inpulsu provocavit ad principem, et iussus ad eius comitatum duci, de fumo, ut aiunt, in flammam traditus Phalangio Baeticae consulari cecidit funesti carnificis manu.

Eminuit autem inter humilia supergressa iam impotentia fines mediocrium delictorum nefanda Clematii cuiusdam Alexandrini nobilis mors repentina; cuius socrus cum misceri sibi generum, flagrans eius amore, non impetraret, ut ferebatur, per palatii pseudothyrum introducta, oblato pretioso reginae monili id adsecuta est, ut ad Honoratum tum comitem orientis formula missa letali omnino scelere nullo contactus idem Clematius nec hiscere nec loqui permissus occideretur.

Horum adventum praedocti speculationibus fidis rectores militum tessera data sollemni armatos omnes celeri eduxere procursu et agiliter praeterito Calycadni fluminis ponte, cuius undarum magnitudo murorum adluit turres, in speciem locavere pugnandi. neque tamen exiluit quisquam nec permissus est congredi. formidabatur enim flagrans vesania manus et superior numero et ruitura sine respectu salutis in ferrum.

Eo adducta re per Isauriam, rege Persarum bellis finitimis inligato repellenteque a conlimitiis suis ferocissimas gentes, quae mente quadam versabili hostiliter eum saepe incessunt et in nos arma moventem aliquotiens iuvant, Nohodares quidam nomine e numero optimatum, incursare Mesopotamiam quotiens copia dederit ordinatus, explorabat nostra sollicite, si repperisset usquam locum vi subita perrupturus.

Post quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huius modi scrutabatur. quae singula narrare non refert, me professione modum, quod evitandum est, excedamus.

Ut enim quisque sibi plurimum confidit et ut quisque maxime virtute et sapientia sic munitus est, ut nullo egeat suaque omnia in se ipso posita iudicet, ita in amicitiis expetendis colendisque maxime excellit. Quid enim? Africanus indigens mei? Minime hercule! ac ne ego quidem illius; sed ego admiratione quadam virtutis eius, ille vicissim opinione fortasse non nulla, quam de meis moribus habebat, me dilexit; auxit benevolentiam consuetudo. Sed quamquam utilitates multae et magnae consecutae sunt, non sunt tamen ab earum spe causae diligendi profectae.

Excogitatum est super his, ut homines quidam ignoti, vilitate ipsa parum cavendi ad colligendos rumores per Antiochiae latera cuncta destinarentur relaturi quae audirent. hi peragranter et dissimulanter honoratorum circulis adsistendo pervadendoque divites domus egentium habitu quicquid noscere poterant vel audire latenter intromissi per posticas in regiam nuntiabant, id observantes conspiratione concordi, ut fingerent quaedam et cognita duplicarent in peius, laudes vero supprimerent Caesaris, quas invitis conpluribus formido malorum inpendentium exprimebat.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a complete example. Don't let us do the work to add a body for the tests.

Comment: I've edited the example. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to achieve what you're after. Here's a run-down of the solution approach:

Break out the `\*mark` macros from the `frontmatter` page style into a separate `\frontmattermarks` macro

```
    \newcommand{\frontmattermarks}{%
      \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\ ##1}}{}} 
      \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{##1}}
    }
```

which you then use after setting `\pagestyle{frontmatter}`.

Here is a complete minimal example showing the suggestions above.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, headheight = 20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,pifont,xspace,setspace,mathptmx,lipsum,etoolbox,fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\frontmattermarks}{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\ ##1}}{}} 
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{##1}}
}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ ##1}}{}} 
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ ##1}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
}

%************************************************
%                                               *
%           COMMANDES PERSONNALISÉES            *
%                                               *
%************************************************

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{frontmatter}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\frontmattermarks

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Première section}

\lipsum[1-20]

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatter}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\chapter{C'est le chapitre 1}

\section{La section 1}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much it's working very fine! 
All the problem is solve by breaking out the '\mark' macros. I've edited your answer by suppressing the 'secnumdepth' comment which does not influence the header and get rid of the chapter in the ToC. 

I have also modified the line of the \chaptermark to have it in capital letter in the frontmatter as it is in the mainmatter headers.